# How do you write an abortable function?

Tags: quitting

How do you wrote an abortable function, so that
when user presses C-g during execution,
this function is "stopped"

```
;; my function so far
(defun my/elfeed-extra-info-2 ()
  (interactive)
  (next-line)
  (message "here1")
  (sleep-for 0.5)
  (next-line)
  (message "here2")
  (sleep-for 0.5)
  (next-line)
  (message "here3")
  (sleep-for 0.5)
  (next-line)
  (message "here4")
  (sleep-for 0.5)
  (next-line)
  (message "here5")
  (sleep-for 0.5)
  (next-line)
  (message "here6")
  (sleep-for 0.5)
  (next-line)
  (message "here7")
  (sleep-for 0.5)
  (next-line)
  (message "here8")
  (sleep-for 0.5)
)
```

Comment: This is pretty much a duplicate of your other question, don't use `sleep-for`.

Comment: This works just fine for me: `C-g` aborts the function.

Comment: In my experience it depends on the operating system whether `quit` works reliable. Under Linux it works perfect (also for `my/elfeed-extra-info-2`) while under cygwin I often have emacs hanging without being able to quit via `C-g`. I have to use `pkill -SIGUSR2 emacs` from the command line in those cases. If you experience problems with your function please extend your question with system information and with a detailed description what happens on your system if you press `C-g`.